# rviz Failing: Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had rviz running fine under Hydro a few days ago but something has gone wrong to cause the following error.  What is this and how do I fix it?

```
user@computer$ rosrun rviz rviz
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.
[ INFO] [1390871921.858315604]: rviz version 1.10.10
[ INFO] [1390871921.858466802]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libroscpp.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros6HeaderC1Ev
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123076/rviz-failing:-symbol-lookup-error/) by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 159 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out thanks to this post: http://answers.ros.org/question/120541/problem-of-running-rosrun-turtlesim-turtlesim_node/

Appears that some system updates inadvertently got crossed.

---

Originally posted by [daalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/9331/daalt/) with karma: 159 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2